# Ruby on rails: Connecting to external Postgresql database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, external

I'm new to Ruby on rails. I created my rails project and I would like to connect to an existing postgresql database (of company I work for) and display then some data in my web app.
Can anybody help out how to do that?

Comment: Have you completed Rails Guides at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/ ?

Comment: Perhaps some code would be helpful here?

Answer (score 2):

These directions assume you are using some version of Linux. However, they would be very similar on other operating systems.

Add the 'postgresql' gem to your Gemfile:

```
 gem 'pg'
```

Then open a terminal window in the root directory of your application and run:

```
 bundle install
```

Edit postgresql.conf (located on the remote postgresql server) and find the line that reads:

```
 #listen_addresses = 'localhost'
```

Remove the comment and change it to:

```
 listen_addresses = '192.168.0.14, localhost'
```

Replace '192.168.0.14' with the ip of your Rails application.

Now open pg_hba.conf (located on the remote postgresql server) and scroll down to:

```
 # Put your actual configuration here
```

Directly below that enter your configuration like so:

```
 # TYPE   DATABASE      USER        ADDRESS        METHOD
 local    all           all         localhost      md5
 host     all           your_user   192.168.0.14   md5
```

After saving both of those files run the command:

```
 sudo service postgresql restart
```

Now edit your Rails application's config/database.yml:

```
 production:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: utf8
   database: the_database_name
   username: your_user
   password: your_database_password
   host: 192.168.0.14
   port: 5432
   pool: 10

 development:
   adapter: postgresql
   encoding: utf8
   database: the_database_name
   username: your_user
   password: your_database_password
   host: 192.168.0.14
   port: 5432
   pool: 10
```

Change 'the_database_name', 'your_user', and 'your_database_password' to the appropriate values.

After that, you should be good.

Comment: Thank you very much, Peter! I will try ;)